# Sequelize how to find rows with multiple where clauses and timestamp > NOW()

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How do I do this with Sequelize?

```
SELECT FROM sessions WHERE user_id = ? AND token = ? AND expires > NOW()
```

Here's what I'm trying to do (assume `Session` is a Sequelize model):

```
Session.find({
    where: {
        user_id: someNumber,
        token: someString,
        //expires > NOW() (how do I do this?)
    }
}).on('success', function (s) { /* things and stuff */ });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

did you try to use the array notation of finders in sequelize?

```
Session.find({
  where: ['user_id=? and token=? and expires > NOW()', someNumber, someString]
}).on('success', function (s) { /* things and stuff */ });
```

You can checkout this page: http://sequelizejs.com/?active=find-objects#find-objects

Hope this works. Otherwise it's a bug :D

Comment: Ahh, my bad... I guess I didn't realize you could have more than one replacement using that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
Session.find({
  where: {
    user_id: someNumber,
    token: someString,
    expires: {
      $gt: (new Date())
    }
  }
}).on('success', function (s) { /* things and stuff */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that as of this posting and the most recent version of sequelize, the above answers are out of date. I am posting the solution that I got working in hopes of saving someone some time.

```
filters["State"] = {$and: [filters["State"], {$not: this.filterSBM()}] };
```

Note the $ and array inside the JSON object and lack of ? token replacement.

Or put in a more general way, since that might help someone wrap their head around it:

```
{ $and: [{"Key1": "Value1"}, {"Key2": "Value2"}] }
```

Comment: I'm happy to change the accepted answer, but I don't have time to test this right now. Perhaps if @sdepold wants to chime in?