# Multiple where with $or sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I trying get all users by provided emails using where clause and $or in sequelize.

[Where in sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/#where)

So i created query from my emails array for multiple where like this:

```
[ { email: 'email1@gmail.com' }, { email: 'email@gmail.com' } ]
```

Then i try to get it in many way for example like that:

```
const allExistedUsers = await User.findAll({
  where: { $or: multileWhere }
});
```

According to  answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390009/sequelize-how-to-find-rows-with-multiple-where-clauses-and-timestamp-now) and doc it should work:

```
{ $and: [{"Key1": "Value1"}, {"Key2": "Value2"}] }
```

But it does not work. I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your E-Mails as Array:

```
const mails = [ { email: 'email1@gmail.com' }, { email: 'email@gmail.com' } ];
const yourEmailsArray = mails.map( el => { return el.email; });
```

Then you can concat your E-Mails. Sequelize formats in:

```
WHERE (`User`.`email` = 'email1@gmail.com' OR `User`.`email` = 'email2@gmail.com')
```

```
const allExistedUsers = await User.findAll({
 where: {      
           email: { [Op.or]: [].concat(yourEmailsArray)}
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using another approach from this post
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695062/sequelize-or-condition-object)

```
const allExistedUsers = await User.findAll({
  where: { email: { [Op.or]: usersEmailsToAssign } }
});
```

usersEmailsToAssign is a array with strings